# TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num' (python)

Tags: python, typeerror, decorator

I want to test the performance of my **long function**.But when I run my program I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Gautham\Desktop\official.py", line 14, in <module>
  def long2(num):
File "C:\Users\Gautham\Desktop\official.py", line 8, in performance
  return wrapper()
TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num'
```

Here is my code:

```
from time import time
def performance(func):
      def wrapper(num):
            t1 = time()
            func(num)
            t2 = time()
            print("Totla Time = %s"%(t2-t1))
      return wrapper()
@performance
def long(num):
      for i in list(range(num)):
            print(i**12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! The issue is that you're returning `wrapper()`, which executes that function (and fails because no argument was passed to it) instead of returning `wrapper`, which is the function itself.

```
from time import time

def performance(func):
    def wrapper(num):
        t1 = time()
        func(num)
        t2 = time()
        print("Totla Time = %s"%(t2-t1))
    return wrapper

@performance
def long(num):
    for i in list(range(num)):
        print(i**12)
```

Comment: @AkshajDev You'll need to provide _some_ function, but it doesn't need to be `long`. For example: `performance(lambda x: None)(0)` <-- pass an inline function to the decorator, then call the returned `wrapper` with any number.

Answer (score 0):

from time import time
def performance(func):
      def wrapper(num):
            t1 = time()
            func(num)
            t2 = time()
            print("Totla Time = %s"%(t2-t1))
      return wrapper
@performance
def long(num):
      for i in list(range(num)):
            print(i**12)
long(4)

Comment: ping me on sachi164@gmail.com